# Конструктор дочернего класса в С++

Tags: c++

Конструктор базового абстрактного класса выглядит так:

```
Object(std::shared_ptr<b2World>& world, const FPoint& pos, const char* nameText, 
    float density, float restitution, TypeShape type);
```

Конструктор дочернего класса выглядит так:

```
Star(std::shared_ptr<b2World>& world, const FPoint& pos, const char* nameText,
    float density, float restitution, Node::TypeShape type);
```

Вопрос: можно ли написать в дочернем классе что-то подобное:

```
Star(Object* object);
```

Компилятор ругается при инициализации объекта дочернего класса объектом абстрактного класса. А не хочется постоянно вводить в дочерние классы параметры базового.

Comment: `TypeShape` и `Node::TypeShape` - это один и тот же тип?

Comment: "Конструктор базового абстрактного класса выглядит так: " Если  класс абстрактный, то не может быть речи о конструкторе. Так у вас класс абстрактный или нет? Если нет, то  введите правку в вопросе

Comment: @ARHovsepyan *"не может быть речи о конструкторе"* А почему нет? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/830b554147173c50

Answer (score 0):

Давайте я попробую угадать, что вам надо.

Вы хотите создать объект Start на основе имеющегося объекта Object? Тогда вам надо нормально описать конструктор Start

```
Start::Start(Object object) // <- тут очень странно почему по указателю
    : Object(*object)
{
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Для этого вам понадобится соответствующий конструктор в наследнике и конструктор копирования в родителе (он есть по умолчанию). Будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
class Alfa {
    public:
        Alfa (int a, int b) {};
};

class Beta : public Alfa {
    public:
        Beta (int a, int b) : Alfa {a, b} {};
        Beta (Alfa &a) : Alfa {a} {};
};
```

Если все-таки хотите использовать указатель, то нужно будет его разыменовать перед инициализацией родительского класса:

```
 Beta (Alfa *a) : Alfa {*a} {};
```

Comment: Окай. Я так и сделал. А как мне инициализировать тогда Beta?  Alfa* a = new Beta(???); Я понять не могу. Всё равно придется использовать конструктор, где много параметров у дочернего класса.

Comment: @Кирилл в соответствии с конструктором, т.е. берете объект базового класса и запихиваете его в Beta при инициализации. Ну или указатель на базовый класс - смотря что вы там хотите

Comment: @Кирилл ну так вы определитесь чего вы хотите! Вы задали конкретный вопрос, а я дал конкретный ответ. То что вы не можете найти применение ответу лишь говорит о том, что не надо было задавать этот вопрос. Сначала подумайте что вам действительно надо и тогда спрашивайте.

Comment: Не пояните ли кто и за что поставил минус?